# Why can't I edit my communities on stackexchange.com?

Tags: feature-request, stackexchange.com, communities-list

On all established SE sites, using the [Stack Exchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66838/276705), you can see your customized list of communities, and a search bar for all SE sites further down.

Clicking the small `edit` link allows you to edit that communities list.

[image: editing communities list]

Now if one were a member of many communities and needed a complete list of their communities, they'd go to their [StackExchange profile page](https://stackexchange.com/users/5361489/scripthero?tab=accounts). Now that they're here, they might as well edit their communities list.

[image: no edit link on stackexchange.com]

Oh.

Comment: Because stackexchange.com has long been a read-only site and you can't do much of anything there except update email subscriptions. Much of the UI and backend for doing most profile-related things does not exist there, because it's not a normal Q&A site. (For example, you can't remove your login credentials there either - only see a list of them.)

Comment: @animuson Understood, [bug] tag removed.  Would still like this feature added for convenience. No point in switching between a community site and stackexchange.com just to update one's communities list.

Comment: This won't happen due to the reason @animuson gave, which is also given in the duplicate question. (I can leave it open, but it will just get a [tag:status-declined])